# Trying to replace a frame which can't decide whether to hide or be visible

Tags: listbox

I have a frame and a function that creates a listbox. When I press a button I want to hide the frame and create a new one, and on this frame I also want to use the create_listbox function. Hiding the frame and creating the new one works perfectly fine. However, when I try to create the listbox on the 2:nd frame the window goes crazy and keeps resizing itself. Here's a simplified version of the program.

```
class App(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.f1 = Frame(self.master)
    self.f1.pack()
    self.f2 = Frame(self.f1)
    self.f2.grid()
    self.create_listbox(self.f1)

def create_listbox(aframe):
    self.listbox = Listbox(aframe)
    self.listbox.pack()

def hide_f2:
    self.f2.grid_forget()
    self.f3 = Frame(self.f1)
    self.create_listbox(self.f1)
```

First I thought that it might be because the listbox object belongs to both f2 and f3 and therefore can't decide whether it should hide or be visible, but now I'm not sure anymore :(

Comment: Oops, forgot to pass the self argument while rewriting the code. But ignore that.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the pack and grid commands? I thought I mixed them correctly but maybe they're causing problems..?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself! Apparently it was the root window that caused the problem. I just deleted the `self.grid()` and everything worked fine again. If someone knows why gridding the root window would cause pack-grid problems I would appreciate an explanation :)